# I am not able to return data from sub activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Now error is showing in my program but it is not its not printing input from my second activity in the text view of main activity.
when i click on the close button it simply takes me to the first activity but doesn't print the the input given in the sub activity in the main activity text view.

> java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Launch(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode==REQUEST_CODE)
            &&(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK))
        {t.setText(data.getStringExtra("secondactivity"));

        }
    }
}
```

> java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Set;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }
    public  void Close(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String data = e.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("secondactivity",data);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: post code here, no photos

Answer (score 1):

after serResault you must finish the second activity.

```
setResault(Activity.RESAULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

Comment: its shows unfortunately,GetResultsSubActivity has stopped

Comment: please add your error log. you should use ```data.getExtras().getString("secondactivity");``` instead of ```data.getStringExtra("secondactivity")```